# inserting a HTML table cell into a excel sheet cell with no id

Tags: html, vba, excel, internet-explorer

i was trying to extract a cell from a HTML table into a excel cell by using a function. the table is like this:

```
                   |   1Q    |   2Q    |   3Q    |
         income    |   23    |   34    |   22    |
         expenses  |   11    |   19    |   10    |
                                  .
                                  .
                                  .
```

i cannot get the elements by id, so i created two loops to look for element by element. the code can find the elements (in my case, the word "expenses" col1 row2) but i don't know how to get the cell value to the right (11 in this case)

```
Dim IE As Object
Dim doc As Object
Dim colTR As Object
Dim colTD As Object
Dim tr As Object
Dim td As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "www.mywebpage.com"

Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop

Set doc = IE.Document

Set colTR = doc.GetElementsByTagName("TR")
For Each tr In colTR
    Set colTD = tr.GetElementsByTagName("TD")
    For Each td In colTD
        If td.innertext = "expenses" Then
        TheValueIWant = tr.item(1).innertext
        End If
    Next td
Next tr

IE.Quit

Set IE = Nothing
Set doc = Nothing
Set colTR = Nothing
Set colTD = Nothing
Set td = Nothing
Set tr = Nothing
```

thanks in advance

Comment: 11 is just more columns over. tough to say from your example data, but maybe 1 or 2 or more. you can do a loop with a `debug.print` to figure it out the first time than adjust the code accordingly. So, it would be `tr.Cells(2).innertext` if it was 2nd column.

Answer (score 0):

Scott is right there is no reason to loop through all the tds.

```
 For Each tr In colTR

    If tr.Cells(0).innerText = "expenses" Then
        TheValueIWant = tr.Cells(1).innerText
        MsgBox TheValueIWant
    End If

 Next
```

Comment: Happy to assist. Sir!